# Android "adb devices" vs Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

When i run eclipse and run the devices are listed in the "android device chooser" window and all goes as planned. But when i tried to do "ADB devices" it says the server is out of date and starts the server again but it show an empty list of devices.

I have a lot of difficulty trying to understand why the devices are listed in eclipse but not in the command line.

Comment: Do you have any more details for us? If so, feel free to edit them in.

Comment: You probably have two versions of adb installed on your machine in different locations, one which eclipse is using and another which is on your command line path...